# Proxy response 304 “We’re sorry but <website> doesn’t work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.”

Tags: vue.js

When fetching to an external API with the following proxy settings, I get the json response and everything is fine, but only when served locally with `npm run serve`. When I build the app with `npm run build` (also with --mode development) and then launch the app from `/dist`, I get this message in the 304 response.

> We're sorry but  doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue

So my promise is empty and also I get this error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

I also tried to build it into a docker image and I get the same error.

`vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "" : "",
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "^/todos": {
        target: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { "^/todos": "/todos" },
        logLevel: "debug",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

`component.vue`

```html
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    fetch(`/todos/1`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((messages) => {
        console.log("messages: ", messages);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("err", err);
  }
}
```

I'm using node v17.9.0 (npm v8.7.0) and latest version of @vue/cli

Comment: "and then launch the app from /dist" - how? This totally depends on it. At this point this isn't specific to Vue or Vue CLI anymore, only your web server.

Comment: using serve -d /dist locally and also compiling it to a nginx in a docker image. I'm missing somthing in the build step?

Comment: No, you're missing something in things you listed. You can't expect a proxy from Vue CLI dev server to work in built prod app. This needs to be done by your web server, or not done at all, because proxying the traffic from external API endpoints in production doesn't look like a good idea in general

Comment: I miss configuring the proxy in nginx. I'll take into account what you said. My intention is to setting this proxy to another service in a k8s cluster. thanks for your help!